# How can an Android app detect if it's on a specific WiFi network?

Tags: android, networking, wifi

How can I detect, in my Android app, if I'm connected to a specific WiFi network?

The app that I'm creating doesn't need to be real secure or anything, just FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class InternetData {
    Activity activity;
    ConnectivityManager connManager;
    NetworkInfo mWifi;

    public InternetData(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
        connManager = (ConnectivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);      
    }

    public boolean hasInternetConnection(){
        if(mWifi.isConnected())
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android.net.wifi.WifiInfo.getSSID
```

In the past, I would also use a method to see if the device on the network i needed to interact with was there or not. If that's your situation.

Answer (score 0):

In general to get info about the active WiFi link:

```
private WifiManager wifiManager;
wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String ssid = info.getSSID();
```